# SPARQL BABELNET Prefix not recognised in DBpedia SNORQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, ontology

I want to reproduce the example from the Babelnet SPARQL Endpoint in DBpedia/Snorql.
I enter the prefixes and the query as such:

```html
PREFIX bn-lemon: <http://babelnet.org/model/babelnet#>
PREFIX lemon: <http://www.lemon-model.net/lemon#>

SELECT ?entries WHERE {
    ?entries a lemon:LexicalEntry .
    ?entries lemon:language ?lang .
    FILTER(?lang = "IT")
} LIMIT 30
```

and I get no result. If I run exactly the same query (without the 2 prefixes) in the Babelnet SPARQL endpoint (https://babelnet.org/sparql/) I get several results. What may be the reason for this? I have hat similar situations when using other prefixes on different subjects outside of DBpedia.

Thank you for the valuable feedback. I have modified my code using SERVICE as such:

```html
PREFIX lemon: <http://lemon-model.net/lemon#>
PREFIX lexinfo: <http://www.lexinfo.net/ontology/2.0/lexinfo#> 

SELECT DISTINCT ?entries WHERE {

SERVICE <http://babelnet.org/rdf/> {

    ?entries a lemon:LexicalEntry .
    ?entries lemon:language ?lang .
    FILTER(?lang = "IT")
}
}
LIMIT 30
```

However the query is blocked for security reasons: *Virtuoso 42000 Error SQ070:SECURITY: Must have select privileges on view DB.DBA.SPARQL_SINV_2 SPARQL query*

I assume that people using a public SPARQL accesspoint like DBpedia sparl have no chance. Are there any alternatives beside installing your own accesspoint?

Comment: just to clarify, you're running a SPARQL query for the BabelNet dataset on the DBpedia SPARQL endpoint which has just loaded the DBpedia dataset - why do you expect any result if no BabelNet data is loaded there? I mean, both are totally different datasets, or not? Is there a particular reason that you expect results?

Comment: Maybe it is a basic misunderstanding of mine. I thought that once I mention the right prefix, the SPARQL engine knows how to get the data. Would it work if I try the SERVICE command? The idea I wanted to implement is to find a way to consolidate data from various sources (like BabelNet, WordNet and a few other) via queries in one standard engine like DBpedia/Snorql.

Comment: the prefix is no indicator where to find the data - it's just used to write prefixed URIs. The SPARQL query does only use the data contained in the underlying SPARQL endpoint.

Comment: And yes, federated querying via `SERVICE` keyword is the intended way for you. But for the public endpoints, this feature might have been disabled.

Comment: there is an obvious reason for disabling this feature on public endpoints as a shared medium. And by the way, your `SERVICE` URI is wrong, it has to be the URI of the SPARQL endpoint, i.e. `https://babelnet.org/sparql/`

Comment: Here you can try it: https://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql - use this query then to see it's working: `prefix lemon: <http://www.lemon-model.net/lemon#>
prefix lexinfo: <http://www.lexinfo.net/ontology/2.0/lexinfo#> 

SELECT DISTINCT ?entries WHERE {
SERVICE <https://babelnet.org/sparql/> {
select ?entries {
    ?entries a lemon:LexicalEntry .
    ?entries lemon:language ?lang .
    FILTER(?lang = "IT")
  
} limit 100
}
}
LIMIT 100`